# Can't find GameObject in new scene in DontDestroyOnLoad

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a `GameController` in `Scene1` and I made it `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

When I loaded `Scene2`, I'm trying to find a `GameObject` in `Scene2` and the thing is `obj2` is `null` but `obj1` is not.

Why?

How could I find the `GameObjectInScene2`?

```c#
public class GameController: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
        GameObject obj1 = GameObject.Find("GameObjectInScene1");
        GameObject obj2 = GameObject.Find("GameObjectInScene2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Start` is not called again since your component already ran it in Scene1

You can register to [`SceneManager.sceneLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) and do the find in the callback instead.

I would also store the references global like

```c#
private GameObject obj1;
private GameObject obj2;

void Start()
{
    // This first line just makes sure the listener isn't added twice
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;

    // Whenever a scene is loaded call OnSceneLoaded
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;   

    obj1 = GameObject.Find("GameObjectInScene1");

    SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
}

void OnDestroy ()
{
    // Always clean up listeners when not needed anymore!
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
}

void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
{
    if(scene.name == "Scene2")
    {
        obj2 = Find("GameObjectInScene2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying and editing my post! You save my day! So even I called `LoadScene("Scene2")` before, `GameObject.Find` will still trying to find the `GameObject` in `Scene1`, am I right?

Comment: It depends how you load your Scenes (single or additive).. by default it is `single` so `Find` will search in the active Scene. From the [docu](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) :`Note: If the game is running with multiple scenes then Find will search in all of them.`